# google sheet : How to give write access only to specific range in a sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to share a single sheet to other users the set permission to **Read-only** and i will only give **write** access to certain range of column. Is it possible ?

For example column A,B,C is read only but users can write to column D.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can go to data, Protected sheets and ranges

[image]